# Monitoring page use with jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I plan to add some basic user usage of multiple html pages. To achieve this I want to introduce as little code changes to existing pages as possible. Here is my approach :

Import `.js` file that contains operations to add listeners to the page and when an event is fired then invoke a function :

```
<title>myTitle</title>
<input id="click" type="submit" value="click"/>
<input id="test" type="textbox" value="test"/>
<a id="href">href</a>

   $('a').click(function(e) {
       var linker = $(this).attr('id');
       var title = $(document).find("title").text();
       var url = window.location.href; 
     sendData(linker+'\n'+title+'\n'+url);       
   });
   $('input').click(function(e) {
       var linker = $(this).attr('id');
       var title = $(document).find("title").text();
       var url = window.location.href;
       sendData(linker+'\n'+title+'\n'+url);     
   });

function sendData(dataToSend) {
    console.log('Sending data \n '+dataToSend)
}
```

for now sendData is just a dummy function, but I plan to modify this to send an ajax request to server endpoint with the dataToSend value.

Is there an alternative method of monitoring what the user clicks instead of coding `a` tags and `input` tags ? There may be other input types that I'm not aware of that may get clicked that will not be tracked ?

fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/g2Rxc/167/

Comment: It all depends on what exactly you want to monitor. You could just as well bind a global click catcher.

Comment: Every input on the page will be tracked, because your jQuery selector is selecting all of them. I can't see how you can miss any?

Comment: @garryp so above code should also catch textarea ?

Comment: $('input, textarea').click(...

Comment: @garryp exactly, so your original statement "your jQuery selector is selecting all of them" is false ?

Comment: No, it selects all the input tags fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `click` events may be added *after* you've imported your listener code, you'll want to use event delegation on the `document` element.

Since you're running jQuery v 1.6, you'll need to use the **[`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)** method:

```
$(document).delegate('*', 'click', function(e) {
  var linker = $(this).attr('id'),
      title = $(document).find("title").text(),
      url = window.location.href; 

  sendData(linker+'\n'+title+'\n'+url);       
  return false;
});
```

[**Fiddle 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/qrhmuej8/)

Later versions of jQuery handle event delegation using the **[`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** method:

```
$(document).on('click', '*', function(e) {
  var linker = $(this).attr('id'),
      title = $(document).find("title").text(),
      url = window.location.href; 

  sendData(linker+'\n'+title+'\n'+url);       
  return false;
});
```

[**Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/476srxkz/)

Comment: thanks, alternatively I could ensure import is last statement of page ? although this is not as effective solution.

Comment: If it's the last statement *and* all events are created immediately after  page load, that would work.  You could simply do `$('*').click(...`.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your click functions do the same thing so you can nest all the elements in a single click event:

```
     $('a,input,textare,..,..').click(function(e) {
           var linker = $(this).attr('id');
           var title = $(document).find("title").text();
           var url = window.location.href; 
         sendData(linker+'\n'+title+'\n'+url);       
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("body").find("*").on("click",function()...
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to plan what do you want to track, before write the code. By doing that you are going to find which elements and events you really want to track. With that in mind you will write something like:

```
$('everyElementSeparatedByComma').on('everyEventSeparatedByComma', function(){
 ...
});
```

A real example:

```
    $('a, input, textarea, form').on('click, change, keypress, submit', function(){
     ...
    });
```

Comment: And let me give you a suggestion. If you are planning to track this interactions on Google Analytics, take a look at this plugin (i'm the author, by the way) and see if you will find useful:

https://github.com/DiegoZoracKy/google-analytics-event-tracking